# Как убрать двоеточие из отчёта?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите пожалуйста убрать двоеточие из отчёта!
Вот мой код:

```
a = [x[x.find(':'):]for x in input().split()]
```

Ответ должен выглядеть вот так:

```
['ztuebs', 'zdhkpq', 'jkyfmo', 'ducsvpq', 'ntsaw']
```

А у меня выводит вот так:

```
[':ztuebs', ':zdhkpq', ':jkyfmo', ':ducsvpq', ':ntsaw']
```

Comment: `x.find(':') + 1`. Но может стоит задействовать `split`? Например, `split(' :')`? Приведите, пожалуйста, входные данные. С ними будет гораздо понятнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
a = [x[x.find(':')+1:]for x in input().split()]
```

Раз срез забирает в начале один лишний символ, левую границу нужно сделать больше на 1